# Simulate a conditional self-join to impute NAs in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(Vessel = c("Hondo", "Whamo", "Hondo", "Delta", "Whamo", "Hondo"),
            PAX = c(250, 252, 249, 353, 252, 250),
            crew = c(35, 63, 36, NA, NA, NA))
```

I would like to impute the NAs using something like a conditional self join where if there is another row in the frame with the same Vessel, it updates the crew value based on the corresponding row (if there are multiple corresponding rows, it can sample the crew value, pick max/min...it won't matter as crew values don't change dramatically...and if there is no corresponding record, it updates crew by round(0.25 * PAX).
I have a feeling ddply would be the way to go here and I apologize for not being able to figure this out on my own...I'm having trouble getting anywhere with this. I would like the final data.frame to look like this:

```
VESSEL     PAX     crew
Hondo      250       35
Whamo      252       63
Hondo      249       36
Delta      353       88
Whamo      254       63
Hondo      250       35
```

Note: PAX and CREW values may vary (CREW varies very little) so the last "Hondo" CREW value could be 35, 36, or something close (but it should be based on the lookup and not the calculation).

Thanks in advance,
--JT

Comment: Is there always only one PAX value for each VESSEL?

Comment: no, but it would likely only vary by 10%...the imputed value using crew would still be more accurate than the calculated imputed value...I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, then I think my answer below should still work (with the uncapitalized column names, of course).

Comment: I apologize...I could have created a better data.frame. I think I've clarified the question to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joran's answer to my poorly worded question, I have a solution, albeit an ugly one...

```
library(plyr)
d <- data.frame(Vessel = c("Hondo", "Whamo", "Hondo", "Delta", "Whamo", "Hondo"),
            PAX = c(250, 252, 249, 353, 252, 250),
            crew = c(35, 63, 36, NA, NA, NA))
crewlookup <- ddply(subset(d, !is.na(d$crew)), .(Vessel),
                function(x) {
                  x[sample(nrow(x),size=1),]
                })
d2 <- join(d, crewlookup, by="Vessel")
colnames(d2)<-c("Vessel","PAX","crew","PAXl","crewl")
d2$crew <- ifelse(is.na(d2$crew),d2$crewl,d2$crew)
d2 <- within(d2, crew[is.na(crew)] <- round(.25 * PAX[is.na(crew)]) )
d <- subset(d2, select = c("Vessel", "PAX", "crew"))
```

Anything more elegant would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using base R:

```
transform(merge(d, aggregate(crew ~ ., d, mean), by=1:2, all.x=T, sort=F), 
          crew=ifelse(!is.na(crew.x), crew.x,
                      ifelse(!is.na(crew.y), crew.y, round(0.25 * PAX))))
```

Note that mean is used to get a unique value for each Vessell/PAX pair. This could just as easily be `head(x, 1)` or whatever.